# How could I have Eclipse export files into a different location than their source?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, bukkit

I am writing a `Bukkit` plugin in `Eclipse` in which I separate different functions into different packages and export each package as its own jar file.

However, I would still like to keep these packages in the same project, rather than separating them into different `Eclipse` projects.  These plugins each have files which must be in the root of the `jar` file, such as `plugin.yml`.  I have moved each jar's files into their respective packages, but these files are put into `plugin.jar\com\Preston159\plugin` rather than in the root of the jar file (`plugin.jar\`), causing the plugin not to work.

Does `Eclipse` have any function to make these files automatically compress into the root of the jar file even though they are contained within the package in the source, or, is this something that I could solve by using `Maven`? My current solution to this problem is to move the files manually after exporting the jar, but this is becoming increasingly annoying.

EDIT:

The project builder XML I ended up using to complete this task can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/mvvVF3Cg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a Build Tool.  There are several supported by Eclipse.  Ant and Maven are now built-in, but there are several build tools that run directly within Eclipse, but Eclipse can also be configured to run an external build tool as well.

Do a quick search on **build.xml** for examples of ANT build jobs.

Unless you're specifically required to use MAVEN for continuous integration, etc. then what you want to accomplish would be easily done with ANT.